# Loop for 2 different CTP with also different taxonomy

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm trying to display the lastest 3 post of 2 different CTP that also has a different Taxonomy. The posts must be order by date, independently of the CTP.

My CTP and it's taxonomies are these:

[My CTP and Taxonomies structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5k6t.png)

Is there a way to add "multiple taxonomies" to the Multiple Loop?

Something like these?

```
<?php 
    // QUERY PARA ARTICULOS Y NOTICIAS

    $args2 = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'noticias', 'articulos'),
        'orderby'    => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'categoria_noticias',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'nacionales',
            ),

            // Another Array for 2nd taxonomy here?
        ),

    );
```

Thanks in advance and sorry about my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to add another array under tax_query and also the relation, if you want to query the posts with at least one of the taxonomies `'relation' => 'OR'` or both taxonomies '`relation' => 'AND'` (as your structure, you need the OR relator I guess)

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'noticias', 'articulos'),
    'orderby'    => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria_noticias',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'nacionales',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria_articulos',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'memoria',
        ),
    ),
);
```